# PayPal button with 'min_amount' AND 'set_customer_limit'

Tags: php, paypal

I have created a **non-hosted** PayPal-Button with a text input to let users define an amount to pay. It's a subscription button.

**Now the problem is that there must be a minimum amount to pay**, say 101 (CHF - Swiss francs).

According to the docs of [PayPal HTML-Variables](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HF00TZS) I have the possibility to add the following vars in hidden inputs to my form to get it to work.

- `set_customer_limit` with a value of `max_limit_own`
- `min_amount` with a value of `101`

**The `set_customer_limit` is working but not the `min_amount`. Any amount is accepted.**

I opened a ticket at the technical support, but no reply till now.

Here's my form:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
    <!-- //... -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="mydomain.com/cancel">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="mydomain.com/paid">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
    <input type="text" name="a3" value="101.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="Y">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CHF">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-SubscriptionsBF:btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<!-- the concerned inputs -->
    <input type="hidden" name="set_customer_limit" value="max_limit_own">
    <input type="hidden" name="min_amount" value="101">
<!-- ---- -->
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/de_DE/CH/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Jetzt einfach, schnell und sicher online bezahlen – mit PayPal.">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/de_DE/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

As for the moment, I just validate the minimum amount with JavaScript, which isn't really secure...

---

**EDIT**

As an idea, I could implement another form (submit it by AJAX, onchange, onkeyup, whatever), which sets the minimum amount given by the user before the PayPal-form and put it into the PayPal-input then (set to hidden again):

```
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="<?php echo $_POST['pre_min_amount'] ?>">
```

That way I could validate the minimum amount with PhP, before submitting the PayPal-form. But that doesn't seem a clean way to me. Really Glad if anybody could give me a hint!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The answer of the PayPal technical support is: **No it is not possible!**

(*Date of answering was 05/02/2015*) Hopefully, this will be possible in the future. If so please post your answer!

---

I'd ***really*** suggest using the [PayPal API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/) for this kind of thing (including creating a developer account, byting thru the docs, etc).

**So this "solution" is a quick & dirty workaround**.

---

First, add a small form (I call it the *`min_amount` -form* for now) to the page (telling the user, he has to set the amount first):

```php
<form id="min_amount" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
    <input type="text" id="pre_min_amount" name="pre_min_amount" value="101">
    <input type="submit" value="Set min. Amount">
</form>
```

Then, add the whole PayPal form to a PHP variable with [NowDoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) and add the posted value from the *`min_amount`-form* to the `a3` input:

```php
$min_amount = 0;
$payPalForm = <<<SOME
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <!-- //... -->
    <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="$min_amount">
</form>
SOME;
```

After submitting, check if the minimum amount is true and then only show the PayPal-form:

```php
if (isset($_POST['pre_min_amount']) && is_numeric($_POST['pre_min_amount']) && floatval($_POST['pre_min_amount']) >= 101) {
    $min_amount = htmlspecialchars($_POST['pre_min_amount']);
    echo $payPalForm;
}
```

As I said, it's quick and dirty (no more time for this project), but you ensure to validate the minimum amount on the server-side, not just with Javascript. You could also submit the *`min_amount`-form* with an AJAX call, but then the return of this call is on the client-side, which isn't really secure either. (Sure you may also)

*BTW, I am not proud of this solution at all, but sometimes, a programmers life is hard and I'm sure all you coders out there had to do some q&d code somehow, somewhere ;-)...*

---

**Update:** *08/05/2015*

All depends on the country in which the concerning account is registered. Full services guaranted by PayPal only in the USA and Canada

Comment: `value="{ $_POST['pre_min_amount'] }"` <- you should sanitize this instead of writing $_POST directly to html

Comment: @Pharaoh not necessary because I test it with `floatval` and if false the form doesn'tshow up

Comment: Assume this string: `200<script>alert('hacked')</script>` It passes the `floatval()` test, but still injects javascript.

Comment: oops... ok convinced!!

Comment: @Pharaoh Fixed with `htmlspecialchars` and `is_numeric`. Thx to Pharaoh for pointing at!